# Exit YouTube fullscreen back button Cordova closes the app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I play a YouTube video in fullscreen mode, and when I press the back button, it closes the app instead of exiting the the full-screen mode. I'm using **JavaScript with Cordova 6.3.1 for Android**. Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
       screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
     }, false);
}
```

The previous code does not work as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found the answer yet, but I'm posting my findings so far in hopes it helps someone.

Version : `cordova-android` 8.1.0

#### What I found

The problem comes from the fact that to display the Youtube video fullscreen, the `SystemWebChromeClient` calls the `CordovaWebViewImpl.showCustomView()` method. By doing so, the new view seems to catch the Back button event before Cordova is able to `onDispatchKeyEvent()` and send the `backbutton` event to the JavaScript side.

Here is some log taken, with comments added for clarity

```
// Video is fullscreen, and then dismissed with the onscreen minimize button
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: showCustomView : showing Custom View + view = android.widget.FrameLayout{a7cc344 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: hideCustomView : Hiding Custom View : mCustomView = android.widget.FrameLayout{a7cc344 V.E...... .......D 0,0-1080,1704}

// While the video is not displayed fullscreen, the back button event is correctly caught and sent to the JS side
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onDispatchKeyEvent : isBackButton = true mCustomView = null

// Once again in fullscreen, then click on the back button
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: showCustomView : showing Custom View + view = android.widget.FrameLayout{fa6d336 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
// No back button event caught
// A destroy lifecycle event is sent (from the video FrameLayout handling?) and handleDestroy() is called
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: handleDestroy : load about:blank
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: >>> loadUrl(about:blank)
W/cr_AwContents: WebView.destroy() called while WebView is still attached to window.
D/CordovaWebViewImpl: hideCustomView : Hiding Custom View : mCustomView = android.widget.FrameLayout{a7cc344 V.E...... .......D 0,0-1080,1704}
```

#### What I tried

- Create a subclass of `FrameLayout`, with overrides for `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()`, use it in `showCustomerView()`

The video then wasn't displayed anymore.

#### Docs

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout